# Default client Content-Type under api-namespace in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I set a default Content-Type for all incoming requests to my Rails app under a given namespace?

In my case I have an `/api` namespace that always expects JSON, but I don't want to force the clients to always set it (they are of cause welcome to do so if they please in which case the Rails app should adhere to the set Content-Type). So it should just default to `application/json`.

This will make testing with `curl` etc A LOT EASIER.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to specify before action in API controller and set JSON format:

```
before_filter :default_request_format

private

def default_request_format
  request.format = :json
end
```

or you can specify JSON format in `routes.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Let all your API-Controller inherit from a Api::Controller class, which only respond_to :json

Example:

```
class Api::Controller < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json
  before_filter :default_request_format

  private

  def default_request_format
    request.format = :json
  end
end
```

Now your other Api Controllers can Inherit from it and will automatically respond with JSON.

For example you have a model called 'FooBar':

```
class Api::FooBarsController < Api::Controller
  def index
    @foobars = FooBar.all
    respond_with(@foobars)
  end
end
```